# Convexity of $f_t(y)=\min_x \left[ \frac{1}{2t}\|x-y\|^2 + f(x) \right]$

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

Given a convex function $f : \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$, I need to show that the following $\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ function is convex

$$ f_t(y) := \min_{x \in \Bbb R^n}\left[ \frac{1}{2t}\|x-y\|^2 + f(x) \right] $$

where $t \in \Bbb R$.

I  know that $ \|x-y\|^2 $ is a convex function of $y$ and therefore for every $x$ we have
\begin{align*}
\|{x-(\lambda y_1 + (1-\lambda)y_2)}\|^2
\leq \lambda \|{x-y_1}\|^2 + (1-\lambda)\|{x-y_2}\|^2
\end{align*}

And now:

\begin{align*}
f_t( \lambda y_1 + (1-\lambda ) y_2 ) &= \min_x \left[ \frac{1}{2t}\|x-(\lambda y_1 + (1-\lambda ) y_2 )\|^2 + f(x)\right]\\
&\le \min_x \left[\frac{1}{2t}  \lambda \|{x-y_1}\|^2 + (1-\lambda)\|{x-y_2}\|^2 + f(x)\right]
\end{align*}

And here I'm stuck.

Comment: Look up infimal convolution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_conjugate#Infimal_convolution.

Comment: This is the Moreau-Yosida regularization of $f$ (so that’s another useful keyword).

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thanks for editing my answer.

Comment: Do you agree with my edits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $t > 0$.

We need to prove that
$$f_t(\lambda y_1 + (1-\lambda)y_2) \le \lambda f_t(y_1) + (1-\lambda)f_t(y_2). \tag{1}$$

Let
$h(x, y) := \frac{1}{2t}\|x - y\|^2 + f(x)$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. There exist $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that
$h(x_1, y_1) \le f_t(y_1) + \epsilon$ and $h(x_2, y_2) \le f_t(y_2) + \epsilon$.

Thus, we have
\begin{align*}
 f_t(\lambda y_1 + (1-\lambda)y_2) &\le h(\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2, \lambda y_1 + (1-\lambda)y_2)\\
 & \le \lambda h(x_1, y_1) + (1-\lambda)h(x_2, y_2) \\
 &\le \lambda (f_t(y_1) + \epsilon) + (1-\lambda)(f_t(y_2) + \epsilon)\\
 & = \lambda f_t(y_1) + (1-\lambda)f_t(y_2) + \epsilon.
\end{align*}
Since this holds for any $\epsilon > 0$, (1) holds.

We are done.

See [1](http://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook), page 88.

*References*

[1](http://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook) Boyd and Vandenberghe, [Convex Optimization](http://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook).

Comment: How did you get to the first line after Thus, we have ?

Comment: @Tomer Because $f_t(y) = \min_{x} h(x,y) \le h(z, y)$ for all $z$.

Comment: How do you know that  There exist $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that
$h(x_1, y_1) \le f_t(y_1) + \epsilon$ and $h(x_2, y_2) \le f_t(y_2) + \epsilon$ ?

Comment: @Tomer $f_t(y) = \min_{x} h(x,y)$. Simply choose $x_1$ to be the minimizer for $y_1$, $x_2$ to be the minimizer for $y_2$, respectively.

Comment: @Tomer Actually, this is for $\inf_{x} h(x, y)$. If you are sure that the minimum is attainable (that is $\min_x h(x,y)$), then we use the minimizers $x_1, x_2$ directly.

Comment: @Tomer In other words, in your case, $f_t(y) = \min_{x} h(x,y)$. Let $f_t(y_1) = h(x_1,y_1)$ and $f_t(y_2) = h(x_2, y_2)$. Then $f_t(\lambda y_1 + (1-\lambda)y_2) \le h(\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2, \lambda y_1 + (1-\lambda)y_2)
 \le \lambda h(x_1, y_1) + (1-\lambda)h(x_2, y_2) 
 = \lambda f_t(y_1) + (1-\lambda)f_t(y_2)$

Comment: This proof is good, but obscures the geometry behind infimal convolution.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x)$ be the first function inside the $\min$.

Note that $f_t(y) = (g \square f)(y) = \min\{ g(x_1) + f(x_2) \mid x_1+x_2 = y \}$. This is called infimal convolution.

Show that $\operatorname{epi} (g \square f) = \operatorname{epi} g + \operatorname{epi}  f$. It follows from this that $g \square f$ is convex.

For a reference, see Rockafellar, "Convex Analysis", Theorem 5.4.

**Addendum**: To show the epigraph equality above.

Suppose $(y,\alpha) \in \operatorname{epi} (g \square f)$. Then $g(x_1)+f(x_2) \le \alpha$ for all $x_1,x_2$ such that $x_1+x_2 = y$. Note that $(x_1,g(x_1)) \in \operatorname{epi} g$ and $(x_2,f(x_2)) \in \operatorname{epi} f$. Since
$(y, g(x_1)+f(x_2))) \in \operatorname{epi} g + \operatorname{epi}  f$ it follows that $ (y,\alpha)) \in \operatorname{epi} g + \operatorname{epi}  f $.

$(x_1,\alpha_1) \in \operatorname{epi} g$ and $(x_2,\alpha_2) \in \operatorname{epi} f$, then
$g(x_1) \le \alpha_1, f(x_2) \le \alpha_2$ and so
$(g \square f)(x_1+x_2) \le g(x_1)+f(x_2) \le \alpha_1+\alpha_2$. Hence
$(x_1,\alpha_1)+(x_2,\alpha_2) \in \operatorname{epi} (g \square f)$.

Comment: I assume you meant $\operatorname{epi} g + \operatorname{epi}  f$

Comment: I can't see why $\operatorname{epi} (g \square f) = \operatorname{epi} g+ \operatorname{epi}  f$. It looks like we are ignoring the constraint - hope you can explain.

Comment: @Tomer I am not sure what constraint you are referring to. I added an elaboration above.